# Is one CUDA block dimension faster than the other?

Tags: cuda

I have a simple CUDA code that assigns the values of an `NxN` matrix `A` to matrix `B`.  In one case, I declare block sizes `block(1,32)` and have each thread loop over the entries in the first matrix dimension.  In the second case, 
I declare block sizes `block(32,1)` and have each thread loop over entries in the 
second matrix dimension.

Is there some really obvious reason why, in my code below, threads that loop over the stride 1 memory are significantly slower than those that the loop over stride N memory?  I would have thought it was the other way around (if there is any difference at all).

Am I missing something really obvious (a bug, perhaps)?

The complete code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

__global__ void addmat_x(int m, int n, int* A, int *B) 
{    
    int idx, ix;
    int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
    if (iy < n) 
        for(ix = 0; ix < m; ix++) {
            idx  = iy*m + ix;    /* iy*m is constant */
            B[idx]   = A[idx];
        }
}

__global__ void addmat_y(int m, int n, int* A, int *B) 
{    
    int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int idx, iy;
    if (ix < m)
        for(iy = 0; iy < n; iy++) {
            idx  = iy*m + ix; 
            B[idx]   = A[idx];        
        }
}

double cpuSecond()
{
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp,NULL);
    return (double) tp.tv_sec + (double)tp.tv_usec*1e-6;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int *A, *B;
    int *dev_A, *dev_B;
    size_t m, n, nbytes;
    double etime, start;

    m = 1 << 14;  
    n = 1 << 14;  
    nbytes = m*n*sizeof(int);

    A = (int*) malloc(nbytes);
    B = (int*) malloc(nbytes);

    memset(A,0,nbytes);

    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_A, nbytes);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_B, nbytes);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_A, A, nbytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

#if 1
    /* One thread per row */
    dim3 block(1,32);  
    dim3 grid(1,(n+block.y-1)/block.y);
    start = cpuSecond();
    addmat_x<<<grid,block>>>(m,n,dev_A, dev_B);
#else
    /* One thread per column */
    dim3 block(32,1);  
    dim3 grid((m+block.x-1)/block.x,1);
    start = cpuSecond();
    addmat_y<<<grid,block>>>(m,n,dev_A, dev_B);
#endif
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    etime = cpuSecond() - start;
    printf("GPU Kernel %10.3g (s)\n",etime);

    cudaFree(dev_A);
    cudaFree(dev_B);
    free(A);
    free(B);

    cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

Comment: 32 threads grouped together in x ie. (32,1) will coalesce on loads and stores.  This is a more efficient use of the GPU memory subsystem.

Comment: @Robert Crovella  Thanks.  In other words, the thread grouping is more important than the layout of global memory access?

Comment: They are related.   In order to do an efficient global load or store, you want adjacent threads in a warp to read adjacent locations in memory, roughly speaking.   This is a very basic GPU programming concept covered in many questions and many tutorials.   In the "good" case, a warp read is behaving something like what is depicted on slide 45 [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf).  In the bad case, a warp read is behaving something like what is depicted on slide 53.

Comment: @Robert Crovella The slides are great.  At the time the warp is launched, how can it be known what global memory addresses will be needed?  A second question is, why does the dimension of 1d threadblocks matter, if they are all treated as 1d arrays by the SM?

Comment: `At the time the warp is launched, how can it be known what global memory addresses will be needed?` You don't know this at the time the warp is launched. You have to inspect the code. You can look at a global memory read operation, and compute the indices that each thread in the warp will generate, just by looking at your code. `why does the dimension of 1d threadblocks matter, if they are all treated as 1d arrays by the SM?` It doesn't matter. What matters is the relationship between the threads and the indexing **created by your code**.  Study the indices your code generates, in each case.

Comment: Hm... now I am confused.  Both versions of my code launch a 1d grid of 512 blocks of  1d threadblocks (32 threads each).   In once case, the arrays of threads is Nx1, and in the other case, it is 1xN.   The only other difference is the global memory access patterns within each thread.  I understand how each kernel uses threadIdx.x, etc to locate data in global memory, but don't understand how this global access pattern is tied to warp execution, particularly, why Mx1 blocks would be favored over 1xM  blocks.

Comment: I suggest you do the legwork to calculate the actual global memory index (`idx`)  generated by each thread, in each case.   I could do that for you, but I don't need the practice. :-)   In one case, you will find they are adjacent as you go from one thread to the next in the warp.  In the other case you will find they are separated quite a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168961/discussion-between-donna-and-robert-crovella).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets compare the global memory indexing generated by each thread, in each case.

```
addmat_x:
```

Your block dimension is (1,32).  This means 1 thread wide in `x`, 32 threads "long" in `y`.  The `threadId.x` value for each thread will be 0.  The `threadIdx.y` value for the threads in the warp will range from 0 to 31, as you move from thread to thread in the warp.  With that, let's inspect your creation of `idx` in that kernel:

```
m = 1 << 14;  
...
int iy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
idx  = iy*m + ix;
```

let's choose the first block, whose `blockIdx.y` is 0.  Then:

```
idx  = threadIdx.y*(1<<14) + ix;
```

For the first loop iteration, `ix` is 0.  The idx values generated by each thread will be:

```
threadIdx.y:   | idx:
   0              0
   1                (1<<14)
   2              2*(1<<14)
  ...
   31            31*(1<<14)
```

For a given loop iteration, the distance from the load or store index from one thread to the next will be 1<<14.  i.e. not adjacent.  Scattered.

```
addmat_y:
```

Your block dimension is (32,1).  This means 32 threads wide in `x`, 1 thread "long" in `y`.  The `threadIdx.y` value for each thread will be 0.  The `threadIdx.x` value for the threads in the warp will range from 0 to 31, as you move from thread to thread.  Now let's inspect your creation of `idx` in that kernel:

```
m = 1 << 14;  
...
int ix = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
idx  = iy*m + ix;
```

Let's choose the first block, whose `blockIdx.x` is 0.  Then:

```
idx  = iy*m + threadIdx.x;
```

For the first loop iteration, `iy` is 0, so we simply have:

```
idx  = threadIdx.x;
```

This generates the following index pattern across the warp:

```
threadIdx.x:   | idx:
   0              0
   1              1
   2              2
  ...
   31            31
```

These indices are adjacent, it is not a scattered load or store, the addresses will coalesce nicely, and this represents "efficient" use of global memory.  It will perform faster than the first case.

Comment: I understand how the global indexing works.  But I come from an MPI background, and failed to appreciate the level of synchronization between threads (as opposed to MPI processes).    The addresses requested at each instruction in the thread are all loaded at once, and so it will be easier to load them if they are contiguous.  It is less important (if it matters at all) that the data accessed in the loops within each thread is contiguous.  Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes, a warp of threads (32) executes in lockstep.  When one issues a global read, all 32 issue a global read.  If the addresses associated with this global read across the warp can "coalesce" nicely (i.e. are grouped together) then the usage of global memory will be more efficient.  I think this should be pretty evident if you read the slide deck I previously linked, for example slide 6.

Comment: The slides are clear now! But in the  MPI/Fortran world, loop ordering is everything and  the goal is to achieve data locality on a process, not between processes (except possibly at communication boundaries, but that is a different issue).   This is a key difference that I now appreciate!